# Error in installing a conda package

Tags: ubuntu, conda

I'm trying to install a conda package(macs2). I've installed conda and, to make sure it is installed, I typed:

```
conda list
```

I got installed packages, so conda is installed.

Then I tried this command to install macs2:

```
conda create --name macs macs2
```

And here is the error:

```
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - macs2

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda macs2
```

I have Ubuntu 64.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the channel from which the package will be downloaded. By default only the `defaults` channel is included in the search, so you have to add the `-c` or `--channel` option and add the correct channel. A search on [Anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search?q=macs2) shows that the correct channel is the `bioconda` channel, so the following should work:

```
conda create -n macs -c bioconda macs2
```

You may want to check out the documentation for Bioconda: https://bioconda.github.io/#set-up-channels